# How can I sort a list of dicts arbitrarily by a particular key?

Tags: python, json, sorting

How can I sort my `list` of `dict`s by their `name` values according to an arbitrary ordering? I want `dict`s with a name of `720p` to come first, then `dict`s with a name of `1080p`, and finally `dict`s with a name of `360p`.

```
hosters = []

for entry in json.loads(aResult[1][0]):
    if 'file' not in entry or 'label' not in entry: continue
        sLabel = sName + ' - ' + entry['label'].encode('utf-8')
        hoster = dict()
        hoster['link'] = entry['file']
        hoster['name'] = sLabel
        hoster['resolveable'] = True
        hosters.append(hoster)
```

Comment: I don't see any output. Do you mean `hosters`? Is `hosters` a list? Descending by what?

Comment: What do you what to sort? Also you create hoster in every iteration again, is that what you want?

Comment: Hosters is a list and I have 2 or sometimes 3 entrys in it. 360p ist the first 720p the second and 1080p the third. I want 720p or 1080p as the first in the list.

Comment: @Unreal, it looks like `hosters` contains _`dict`s_, not strings. What do you mean that "360p ist the first 720p the second and 1080p the third"? Are those values for a particular key in each `dict` (possibly `hoster['name']`)? Note that with lexicographic sorting `1080p` will come _before_ `360p`. What are the sorting rules that you wish to use?

Comment: Right dict and i think hoster name is the output that gives me the 360p and 720p to chose from. I want the 720p before 360p and if 1080p (not on every stream) also available i want the 720p still before all others.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use a custom sorting function. Something like this should work:

```
def sort_by_resolution(hoster):
    desired_order = ['720p', '1080p', '360p']
    if hoster['name'] in desired_order:
        return desired_order.index(hoster['name'])
    else:
        return len(desired_order)

sorted(foo, key=sort_by_resolution)
# [{'name': '720p'}, {'name': '1080p'}, {'name': '360p'}]
```